# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "BY": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite3

Hola estoy aprendiendo slqite3 y me esta surgiendo un problema que no consigo resolver y trata de que cuando ejecuto el código siguiente me da el error del título "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "BY": syntax error". ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("usr_and_passw.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute(
    """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios_and_passwords(
    author TEXTO,
    author_id TEXTO,
    usuarios TEXTO, 
    passwords TEXTO) 
    """)

def show_part_base(argument):
    instruccion = f"SELECT * FROM usuarios_and_passwords ORDERED BY {argument}"
    c.execute(instruccion) 
    datos = c.fetchall()
    print(datos)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás utilizando una **palabra clave** incorrecta para ordenar los resultados en SQLite. La *keyword* correcta es `ORDER BY`, no *ORDERED BY.*

Hasta donde conozco, no hay ningún sistema gestor de bases de datos relacionales de uso generalizado que emplee una cláusula diferente de `ORDER BY` para ordenar los resultados de una consulta. Esta es utilizada entre otras por las bases de datos MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle Database, Microsoft SQL Server (Transact-SQL) y SQLite.

Como norma general, las palabras clave de este lenguaje se usan en **infinitivo** (ADD, ALTER, DROP, CREATE, EXISTS, GROUP BY, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, JOIN, SELECT, SET, UPDATE, etc). Una excepción notable es la cláusula `HAVING`.